# Displaying error message without moving elements located under

Tags: css

[image]

The goal is to add a text error message without moving the element 4. Is it possible with css or javascript ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I think you need to give the parent element containing the possible error message a height, so when an error message is shown it will just "replace" the already empty space.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @NathanQ thanks that would be the more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't want especially someone to code it for me but to give me a direction how to do it. I understand your concern though.

Answer (score 6):

When you add an element to the document flow, it will take up some space, causing the content below it to move down. To prevent this from happening, you have basically two options:

1. **Keep the element out of the flow.** There are several ways to achieve this, one possible being `position: absolute`.
2. **Have the element take up its required space even when not visible.** You could keep the element in the flow, but hide it using `opacity: 0` or maybe `visibility: hidden`. That way the space it needs is already reserved in the flow.

Answer (score 3):

`position:absolute` or negative `margin`

```css
div{
  height:24px;
  margin:10px 10px 0;
  border:1px solid;
}
.somethinglarger{
  margin-top:40px;
  height:36px;
}
.error{
  margin-bottom:-36px; /* 24px-height, 10px-margin top, 2px-border*/
}
.error2{
  position:absolute;
  
}
.col{
  width:30%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 1
</div>
<div>
  Content 2
</div>
<div>
  Content 3
</div>
<!--div class="error">
  Error message
</div-->
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 4
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 1
</div>
<div>
  Content 2
</div>
<div>
  Content 3
</div>
<div class="error">
  Error message
</div>
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 4
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 1
</div>
<div>
  Content 2
</div>
<div>
  Content 3
</div>
<div class="error2">
  Error message
</div>
<div class="somethinglarger">
  Content 4
</div>
</div>
```